# Overlapping contours

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to draw multiple contours on an image and by far I have managed to draw the contours by applying different thresholds. The only problem is that most of the contour regions are overlapping and I am stuck here on how to deal with it. What I would ideally want is that whenever there is an overlap it should divide the contours into individual regions. For instance, as in the [Conceptual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLsp0.jpg) there are 4 regions(contours) orange, green, blue and black. Whenever there is an overlap, it should divide into purple regions. It seems very tricky and I am not even sure if that is possible. If not, I would want all the overlapping to merge. Can anyone help with how to solve this issue?
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMGq1.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = cv.imread('images/sample.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret1, thresh1 = cv.threshold(imgray, 30, 80, 0)
ret2, thresh2 = cv.threshold(imgray, 80, 110, 0)
ret3, thresh3 = cv.threshold(imgray, 110, 150, 0)
ret4, thresh4 = cv.threshold(imgray, 150, 200, 0)
ret5, thresh5 = cv.threshold(imgray, 200, 255, 0)
_,contours1, hierarchy1 = cv.findContours(thresh1, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_,contours2, hierarchy2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_,contours3, hierarchy3 = cv2.findContours(thresh3,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_,contours4, hierarchy4 = cv2.findContours(thresh4,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_,contours5, hierarchy5 = cv2.findContours(thresh5,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)



cv2.drawContours(im, contours1, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours2, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours3, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours4, -1, (10, 200, 200), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours5, -1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("im",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Is that your actual input image, or just some visualization? If the latter, please post an actual input image. An expensive way would be to draw the filled contours on separate masks and for each two contours compute the intersection and find the contour of that. As I said, that'll be expensive, but will give exact results, I assume.

Comment: @HansHirse that is just a conceptual image to get the understanding of the problem. I have attached the sample image.

Comment: @HansHirse if we have say 10 overlapping contours then that would take a lot of computational time to find the regions. Is there any other method?

Comment: Not necessarily. I guess, that approach will be memory-intensive, but not that computationally expensive, since the single operations are very basic.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, generating masks from your contours, and then calculate the pair-wise intersections as well as the "exclusive" parts from the original masks, will certainly give you the desired regions, but this approach will tend to be expensive as well. From your sample image and your code, I couldn't figure out, what you actually want to do, so I stick to some very basic example to illustrate that approach.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate some dummy images, whose (main) contours overlap
img1 = cv2.circle(np.zeros((400, 400, 3), np.uint8), (150, 150), 100, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
img2 = cv2.rectangle(np.zeros((400, 400, 3), np.uint8), (175, 175), (325, 325), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours (OpenCV 4.x)
contours1, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours2, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Find contours (OpenCV 3.x)
#_, contours1, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
#_, contours2, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Generate masks of (main) contours; Attention: Hard-coded selection of first contour here!
mask1 = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros((400, 400), np.uint8), [contours1[0]], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)
mask2 = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros((400, 400), np.uint8), [contours2[0]], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Find intersection of both masks
mask_combined = cv2.bitwise_and(mask1, mask2)

# Generate "exclusive" masks, i.e. masks without the intersection parts
mask1_excl = cv2.bitwise_xor(mask1, mask_combined)
mask2_excl = cv2.bitwise_xor(mask2, mask_combined)

# Visualization
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(3, 3, 1), plt.imshow(img1), plt.ylabel('img1')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 2), plt.imshow(img2), plt.ylabel('img2')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 3), plt.imshow(img1 + img2), plt.ylabel('img1 + img2')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 4), plt.imshow(mask1, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask1')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 5), plt.imshow(mask2, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask2')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 6), plt.imshow(mask_combined, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask_combined')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 7), plt.imshow(mask1_excl, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask1_excl')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 8), plt.imshow(mask2_excl, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask2_excl')
plt.subplot(3, 3, 9), plt.imshow(mask_combined, cmap='gray'), plt.ylabel('mask_combined')
plt.show()
```

Visualization:

[image: Visualization]

Now, this has to be done for each tuple of contours - not only pairs, since you can have intersections of three or more contours. To keep track of all those resulting masks, etc. will be most likely memory-intensive, but not that computationally expensive. In the end, all approaches will somehow need to store the resulting regions as some kind of masks.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it looks amazing but what I wanted to achieve was that it should generate 3 regions in the last diagram. One circle(without intersecting region), one square(intersecting region) and one the intersecting region. Each should have a boundary across to differentiate that they are individual regions

Comment: and by "each tuple of contours- not only pairs" do you mean every possible combination like contour1 with contour2,3,4,5 and then contour 2 with 3,4,5 and so on?

Comment: @Happy Even more: `c1` combined solely with `c2`, solely with `c3`, and so on. Then also, `c1` combined with `c2` and `c3`, `c1` combined with `c3` and `c4`, and so on. That means, you need all *k*-combinations without repetition for *k = 2, ..., n*.

Comment: So for each combination do we need to hard code the same procedure?

Comment: @Happy (a) You store all contours in one list. (b) You calculate all possible *k*-combinations for *k = 2, ..., n*, and store these in another list. (For example: For `n = 3`, you'll get `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]`) (c) You iterate the combinations list, and pick all contours corresponding to the contained indices, and generate the intersections and exclusive masks as described above. All that can be done using loops and stuff, you don't need to hard-code anything. But, in fact, that's still a lot of work, but further, individual assistance is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow here.

Comment: appreciate it. I'll give this a try and see how far I can go.