# Weird results when subtracting a mask from a contour in OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I would like to subtract a mask (blue) from a contour (red):

[image: mask and contour pictured]

I'm using the following code, simplified here but the methods are the same:

```
# Get first image and its mask
img1_gray = cv.cvtColor(cv.imread("image1.png"), cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshhold, theMask = cv.threshold(img1_gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# Get second image, its mask and contours
img2_gray = cv.cvtColor(cv.imread("image2.png"), cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshhold, theContourMask = cv.threshold(img2_gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY
theContours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(theContourMask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# "Subtract" first mask from second contour
nonzeroMask = cv.findNonZero(theMask)
inner = []
outer = []
for contour in theContours[0]:
    if contour in nonzeroMask:
        inner.append(contour)
    else:
        outer.append(contour)
```

And get the following lengths for the lists:

```
 len(inner): 198
 len(outer): 2
```

This doesn't make sense as it should be a lot closer to 50/50.

I'm new to OpenCV and can't figure it why.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Also, if you'd like to take a look, these are the input images used: [input images](https://imgur.com/a/JGb9PUe)

Comment: Perhaps reverse your test and for each point in nonzeroMask for each blue region test if inside the contour.  That is the area inner. The difference between that and the area of the contour would be the area outer.  See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722.  Get separate masks from either connectedComponents or from contours of the blue regions.

Comment: I am not the best Python coder, but I am suspicious of `contour in nonzeroMask`.  What do you think that is doing functionally?  Is it testing every point on the contour or every pixel inside the contour for a match with each point of the nonzeroMask?  That statement does not look correct to me. I would suggest reversing the process as I stated above.

Comment: You could also check for the intersection of two contours after extracting contours for the blue regions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641425/check-if-two-contours-intersect and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812081/overlapping-contours

Comment: what do you have that you calculate the contour _of_? question needs detail. -- your pseudocode ("simplified") makes no sense. please don't say it does. cv.findNonZero returns a list of points. you run `for contour in theContours[0]`, so either you have a contour, which is a list of points, or you actually have individual points there, in which case the loop variable is named misleadingly. -- further, inclusion tests ought to be done on the mask itself. DO NOT get a list of points for a mask, and then look for a point in there. that's utterly unreasonable. must never be done. it's a war crime.

Comment: I added more of the code to further clarify the methods used.
Thanks @fmw42 for the ideas, I will to implement them and test the new approaches.

Comment: Also thanks @ChristophRackwitz
Both 'theContours[0]' and 'theMask' are a list of points. A 'contour' is just a single 2D point. Thats why I figured a 'for ... in ...' check would work.
Sorry for the confusion with the variable names!

Comment: It is always a good idea to show your input images so other people can run your code and suggest changes.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 for the suggestion. I edited my question and added the input images.